# jQuery toggleclass by information form an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, toggleclass

I am making a jQuery board game and I need to move a counter around the board. I can do with with hard coding but I need to be able to do it depending on what the person rolls on a dice (random number gen). all the squares have their own id and all of those id's are in an array. i have managed to get the code to call the correct square id but what i need is to be able to tell my jquery that is the one that needs its class to be toggled.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(moveto).toggleClass('circle1');
});
```

as you will see from the code, the bit that needs to change is the selector in the jQuery right at the bottom (currently called moveto) and that needs to match what ever var moveto outputs.

Sorry if this is worded a little wierd, if you need any cleared up please ask :)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdSDz/

Comment: sorry, you will probably need to read the jsfiddle to understand. Moveto is a variable that i defined that pulls which square i need to move to from an array.

Comment: i didnt know how the jquery should look so i just put it there. Im aware that probably isnt where it should go though lol. basically the value of moveto should be the id of the square that needs to be toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were after:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var dice = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*6);
    $('#youthrew').text("You threw a " + dice);
    moves = moves + dice;
    $('div').removeClass('circle1');
    $(titles[moves]).addClass('circle1');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WdSDz/7/
?

Comment: sorry andy, are you still around? im having a bit of trouble getting this to work, Just copied the code over into my editor and it have stopped working... yet it works fine on jsfiddle. any ideas?

Comment: @DanielBowen did you see i removed the onClick from the button and used $('input').click(.. instead?